# TypeError: ('sequence item 0: expected string, numpy.int64 found', u'occurred at index 1')

Tags: python, pandas

I am calculating the frequency of each sequence in `df`:

```
VD_1    VD_2    VD_2
35000   35090   31550
35000   35090   31550
35099   45097   
35099   45097   
35099   45097
```

If I do run the code given below, I get an error `TypeError: ('sequence item 0: expected string, numpy.int64 found', u'occurred at index 1')`. In fact, the code works fine on the other dataset, but here it fails:

```
df['data'] = df.apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
df = df.data.value_counts().rename_axis('count').reset_index()
df
```

The result should be this one:

```
data                count
35000/35090/31550   2
35099/45097         1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need add `astype(str)` for cast `int` to `string`:

```
df['data'] = df.apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
```